# Is there any way to find out how many hits you receive from bots, on an IIS6 site?

Tags: iis-6

Is there any way to figure out how many bots (even if it's just one type of bot) that hits our site, on a daily, weekly and monthly average?

we have the standard IIS6 web site logs in lots of files.

Any tricks or recommendations?

#### Update

Program needs to be .NET based. No php or extra ugly packages, please. Free would be a bonus.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many reporting packages can report on this.

For instance, [Awstats](http://awstats.sourceforge.net/docs/index.html) says

> AWStats is able to detect robots
>   visits.[...] "Robots visitors"
>   are reported separately in the
>   "Robots/Spiders visitors" chart.

EDIT: AWStats is free, written in Perl, and works just fine on Windows and with IIS logs.

Comment: I've updated my original post. Bascially, i can't use PHP. has to be .NET based ... and preferably free.

Comment: AWStats is based on Perl, not PHP.

Comment: AWstats has only very basic bot-detection. Anything that has a non-robot useragent and does not request robots.txt is not recognised as a robot.

Comment: re: Php/Perl. opps. I ment Perl, but same thing.. i don't want to install extra stuff besides the app iteself.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a pretty good list of known bot user-agents.  I am not familiar with any free web log analytic tools written in .NET, but you could easily parse the logs yourself if all you are looking for are bots.

[http://www.user-agents.org](http://www.user-agents.org/)

Answer (score 1):

[Google Analytics](http://www.google.com/analytics/) anyone? Free, Javascript based, so no need for server side languages. In depth coverage of hits<s>, bots too.</s>

Comment: I'm already using Google Analytics. It has stats on it's own robot hits?

Comment: Hm, sorry I misled you, I thought GA did bots too. The bots/crawlers can't execute Javascript, Awstats would work for you since it reads the server logs.

Comment: I didn't know this, but Google Analytics actually records how many times it hits your site. That said, it doesn't count the OTHER bots, though.

Answer (score 0):

I use [WebLog Expert](http://www.weblogexpert.com/) when I want to examine our logs. There is a free version (lite) but that doesn't include the scheduler or command line functionality. The software itself runs as a desktop app (either remotely with ability to FTP logs or can be installed on the server), and can output reports in CSV, PDF and HTML.

Answer (score 0):

why not outsourcing your web stats ? With solution like sitemeter, you just put an extra javascript, and they will give you stats on your site.

Web stats may be a pain for admin, doesn't always worth it to implement in house solution