# Free tool for analysis of IIS logfiles?

Tags: iis, log-files, analysis

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Any freeware IIS log analyzer?](https://serverfault.com/questions/13676/any-freeware-iis-log-analyzer)

Hi there,

what are the best free tools available to analyze IIS logfiles?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This question has been asked before - 
http://serverfault.com/questions/13676/any-freeware-iis-log-analyzer
 and http://serverfault.com/questions/21830/analyse-iis-log-files and 
http://serverfault.com/questions/10674/is-there-any-way-to-find-out-how-many-hits-you-receive-from-bots-on-an-iis6-site

Answer (score 0):

I've always been happy with the reports from Analog - http://www.analog.cx/